# Error:<identifier> expected in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and got this error

error: expected
package com.companyname.final;

This error is in auto-generated file which I haven't modified

```
package com.companyname.final; ////ERROR HERE

public final class R {
public static final class anim {
public static final int abc_fade_in=0x7f010000;
public static final int abc_fade_out=0x7f010001;
public static final int abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom=0x7f010002;
public static final int abc_popup_enter=0x7f010003;
public static final int abc_popup_exit=0x7f010004;
public static final int abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom=0x7f010005;
public static final int abc_slide_in_bottom=0x7f010006;
public static final int abc_slide_in_top=0x7f010007;
public static final int abc_slide_out_bottom=0x7f010008;
public static final int abc_slide_out_top=0x7f010009;
public static final int abc_tooltip_enter=0x7f01000a;
public static final int abc_tooltip_exit=0x7f01000b;
public static final int design_bottom_sheet_slide_in=0x7f01000c;
public static final int design_bottom_sheet_slide_out=0x7f01000d;
public static final int design_snackbar_in=0x7f01000e;
public static final int design_snackbar_out=0x7f01000f;
public static final int enterfromleft=0x7f010010;
public static final int enterfromright=0x7f010011;
public static final int exittoleft=0x7f010012;
public static final int exittoright=0x7f010013;
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar issue maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731767/android-r-java-error-identifier-expected.

Comment: I have seen that, but seems both are different. I tried changing the project name(it was "final" initially). Changing the project name worked fine(not sure if this is the actual solution to the problem)

Comment: Yeah, it is. You can't use `final` in a package name. That was the problem, there.

Answer (score 0):

Using "final" as package name was the error here. Changed the project name and everything works fine

Comment: Because `final` is a *reserved word* in Java.